# Customising tooltip in geocharts

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geomap

In the given example given below

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart.html#Example

When i put my mouse the region in tooltip both population and area are displayed
Is there any way possible to display only any one of these variable(either population or area)

```
  function drawMarkersMap() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'City');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Population');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Area');
  data.addRows([
    ['Rome', 2761477, 1285.31],
    ['Milan', 1324110, 181.76],
    ['Naples', 959574, 117.27],
    ['Turin', 907563, 130.17],
    ['Palermo', 655875, 158.9],
    ['Genoa', 607906, 243.60],
    ['Bologna', 380181, 140.7],
    ['Florence', 371282, 102.41]
  ]);

  var options = {
    region: 'IT',
    displayMode: 'markers',
    colorAxis: {colors: ['green', 'blue']}
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this NOT TESTED

```
function drawMarkersMap() {
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'City');
data.addColumn('number', 'Population');
data.addRows([
['Rome', 2761477],
['Milan', 1324110],
['Naples', 959574],
['Turin', 907563],
['Palermo', 655875],
['Genoa', 607906],
['Bologna', 380181],
['Florence', 371282]
]);

var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'City');
data.addColumn('number', 'Area');
data.addRows([

['Rome', 1285.31],
['Milan', 181.76],
['Naples',  117.27],
['Turin',  130.17],
['Palermo',  158.9],
['Genoa',  243.60],
['Bologna',  140.7],
['Florence',  102.41]
]);
  var options = {
 region: 'IT',
 displayMode: 'markers',
 colorAxis: {colors: ['green', 'blue']}
};
if(condition1){
var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
} else{
var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my answer to another similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11956132/254156). It's a matter of applying a pattern formatter and then creating a separate view for the data.